# Case Articles Tool in the Sidebar of Case Feed Page Layout

Tags: visualforce-component, case, service-cloud-console, servicecloud, casefeed

I have created a visualforce page (code given below) to show articles related to Case and keyword search for articles. This component is displayed as a sidebar in the case feed page layout.

The sidebar is displayed and works in the Case detail page and edit page. But, when I click the New Case button in the console and choose a record Type, it displays **"This component is only supported for Case objects."** in the New Case page layout sidebar (both developer and enterprise editions). Any ideas on what's causing this issue?

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <style>       
        .SidebarHeader {
        background-color: #5882FA;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;    
        }
    </style>
    <div>
        <div class="SidebarHeader">
            Articles Sidebar
        </div>
        <support:caseArticles caseId="{!case.id}" 
                              bodyHeight="auto" 
                              attachToEmailEnabled="true"
                              titlebarStyle="none" 
                              searchButtonName="Search"
                              searchFieldWidth="200px"
                              defaultSearchType="lastPublished" 
                              />
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

**Case Detail Page**

[image]

**New Case Page Layout** (Sidebar Error)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the  component is looking for a case ID to use. Because it's on a New Case tab there is no ID so it fails. This is the resulting, and somewhat confusing, error message.

If you continue to save the case record the sidebar will refresh and work properly.

I've logged a bug and you can track its status on the Known Issues page
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008cREAAY